# Hiding bottom tabbar on certain pages in react-native using react-navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to hide the bottom tabbar in certain pages without success.

My router is setup like:

- Root: switchNav

  - SignedIn: bottomTabNav

    - Jobs: StackNav

      - Page One: Screen
      - Page Two: Screen <-- this one needs to hide
    - Earning: Screen
  - SignedOut: StackNav

    - Signin: Screen
    - Signup: Screen

tabBarComponent: CustomTabs

I have tried 2 ways:

1. simple setting tabBarVisible on Page Two. Doesn't work

```
static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarVisible: false
};

or 

//Edit, forgot to add this
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    tabBarVisible: false
})
```

2. seems like a hacky way

Page Two

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.props.navigation.setParams({visible: false});
}
```

CustomTabs

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state={}){
    console.log(props.navigation.getParam('visible', 0));
}

or using componentWillReceiveProps()
```

The idea is to try to get an event to see if this Page two is loaded, and set the  to be invisible in that CustomTabs.

I'm getting nothing from the getParam, I'm assuming it's because this page is inside the stackNav and cannot be passed to the tabNav. However, getDerivedStateProps in CustomTabs page do get an event emitted to it when Page Two finishes loading and calls componentDidMount.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```js
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    tabBarVisible: false
})
```

instead of

```js
static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarVisible: false
};
```

It has helped me in some cases